# The limit is positive is the sequence bounded uniformly?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sequence-of-function

Recently, I read this [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82025484.pdf) about $L^p$ Minkowski problem. In page $84$, it said that

> From $u_0>0$, one can see that there exist constants $m$ and $M$, s.t.  $$0<m\leq\frac{1}{u_k}\leq M.$$
> Here $u_k \rightharpoonup u_0$ in $H^1(S)$.

I wonder how it works. I think $m$ and $M$ are related to $u_0$, but if $u_0$ is bounded is unknown. So how we find the constants $m$ and $M$? I wonder the details of this step. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is the sphere $S^1$, so it is compact. Also $H^1(S)$ is compactly embedded in $C(S)$ (see equation above (17)). $u_0>0$ implies that $u_0\ge 2m$ for some $m>0$ as $u_0$ is continuous on the compact set $S$.

Comment: Oh, thank you @daw . But how to show it show $u_0$ is continuous? For the equation above (17) we can only get $u_0 \in C^{\beta} \; \beta<\frac{1}{2}$ not $C(S)$. We can said $u_0$ is Holder continuous but may not continuous.

Comment: Hoelder continuous $\Rightarrow$ continuous ...

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much!